# PHP: Regex match string not preceded by number or space

Tags: php, regex, string, numbers

I've been trying to check if a string value starts with a numerical value or space and act accordingly, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here is my code:

```
private static function ParseGamertag( $gamertag )
{

    $safetag = preg_replace( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/", "", $gamertag ); // Remove all illegal characters : works
    $safetag = preg_replace( "/[\s]+/", "\s", $safetag ); // Replace all 1 or more space characters with only 1 space : works
    $safetag = preg_replace( "/\s/", "%20", $safetag ); // Encode the space characters : works

    if ( preg_match( "/[^\d\s][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*/", $safetag ) ) // Match a string that does not start with numerical value : not working
        return ( $safetag );
    else
        return ( null );

}
```

So `hiphop112` is valid but `112hiphip` is not valid. `0down` is not valid.

The first character *must* be an alphabetical character `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to anchor your pattern to the start of the string using an anchor `^`

```
preg_match( "/^[^\d\s][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*/", $safetag )
```

Otherwise your regex will find a valid match somewhere within the string

You can find a explanation of anchors [here on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Note the different meaning of the `^`. Outside a character class its an anchor for the start of the string and inside a character class at the first position its the negation of the class.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the `^` to signify the beginning of the string...

```
preg_match( "/^[^\d\s][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*/", $safetag )
```

also, if the first character has to be a letter, this might be better:

```
preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*/", $safetag )
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `^` to mark the beginning of the string (although `^` inside `[ ]` means *not*).

You can also use `\w` in place of `a-zA-Z0-9`

```
/^[^\d\s][\w\s]*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the "begins with carrot" at the beginning of the regex:

```
/^[^\d\s][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*/
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing, nothing will match \s as you have replaced all spaces by %20.

Why not just match positively:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s]*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match( "/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*/", $safetag ) )
```